# .Net Core Project Reference Inheritance

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I noticed when using .net core 2.2 if you add a project reference to another project those project references are available to other projects that reference the original project.

For example:

If you have a 3 projects, let's say UI, Services, and DAL. If you have a reference to Services from UI and Services has a reference to DAL. With that set up, you will notice you will be able to add a using statement and gain access to classes in the DAL project from the IU project. Whats the reasoning behind this and can it be disabled?

UI
-- project references
---- Services

Services
-- project references
---- DAL

Comment: With the simple example above, I wouldn't want my UI to have access to my DAL (entity models).

Comment: You might be able to do something with [PrivateAssets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha#controlling-dependency-assets) for that.

Answer (score 7):

I took @Kirk Larkin comment and made it work for me, however I had to use "ExcludeAssets" instead:

Imagine something like this:

-- GUI

---- Business layer dll

------ Data access layer dll

```
Inside the Business layer dll project file (csproj):

<ProjectReference Include="..\..\DALProject\DALProject\DALProject.csproj">
  <ExcludeAssets>compile</ExcludeAssets>
</ProjectReference>
```

With this, I can no longer reference DALProject methods from my GUI layer where it's not directly referenced.  This method also includes all the supporting DLL's for runtime use.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ExcludeAssets information came from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha#controlling-dependency-assets

Answer (score -6):

This is not unique to .NET Core. It works the same way with .NET Framework, .NET Standard, etc. It's the way virtually all programming languages work. If A has a dependency on B, and B has a dependency on C, then A *also* has a dependency on C. There's no way around that. All the libraries must be satisfied, top to bottom for the entire application to function. It's perhaps just a bit more obvious that this occurring with .NET languages as all the dependencies are separate DLLs and each comes along for the ride.

Comment: I understand the dependency chain, that makes sense. But, if you create the project structure I referenced in a .NET Framework project you will not have access to the chained references via a using statement. It's more of a why is visual studio allowing me to do this when it didn't before question.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's not Visual Studio "allowing" you to do something, and even if it was then Visual Studio has *always* allowed you to do this. Again, this same thing would happen with .NET Framework. It's not new or unique to Core. It's literally due to the fact that your project has an implicit dependency on the DAL. As such, it's the same as if you directly added the DAL as a project reference, and thus, of course you can add usings, just as you could to *any* dependency.

Comment: If you're looking at this from a tiered architecture perspective, that's for structuring your code and keeping like things together. It has nothing to do with segregating dependencies. That's not how this works. If you want to truly abstract your DAL, then you literally need a separate project, turning your service layer into an *actual* HTTP service or something. Then, your UI would truly have no dependency on the DAL. Short of that, it is what is.

Comment: If you create a console app using .net framework and add two new projects, both .net framework class libraries, and set up the project references as described I can only access the classes from the project I directly referenced. Try that with .net core and you see it works differently (like you are explaining and I am questioning).

Comment: Again, not sure what you're talking about because that it will work the same in .NET Framework.

Comment: There is a difference between using `PackageReference` and the traditional `packages.config` approach in terms of requiring a NuGet-level reference to a package that you want to consume directly. I'm trying to find docs about it but  I believe that what the OP is saying is true in that case.

Comment: I can confirm what the original poster is talking about.  I have a .net framework 4.8 application that has a WPF project, business layer project and a datastore project.

The WPF project cannot talk directly to the datastore project in this project in the same solution, and it's been like this forever.

I'm working with a .net core 3.0 project where I add a reference in the business layer and the GUI layer above it can see and use that reference even though the GUI has no reference to it itself.

Dunno if this is just a .net core 'feature' or not though.